# Only clickable if logged in paypal button

Tags: php, paypal

I just need your help with this paypal checkout button. sorry I cant show you all the code. But the way I have set up this button is that it only shows when something is in the cart and when you have someone and click on the `button` it takes you directly to paypal website.

**My question** 
I want to show as it is as now but `I only want it to  clickable if the user is logged`.
The `if` statement below is what I want to check if someone is logged it or not

```
if ($_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] == null) {
```

**What I wanted to try**

I want to make a fake paypal image of a button and but it when the user is not clicked it and then show the real one, when the user is logged it but that is not professional.

Please can someone share with me any method they would use?

**Bonus question**

Anyone know why paypal sandbox is not working for non-US country? it wouldnt even let me register

Answer (score 0):

This is  how  you can disable a button if user is not logged in

Check  if the user is logged in

```
if ($_SESSION['User']['AccessLvl'] == null) { 
?>
    <input type="Submit" value="Buy Now" disabled="disabled"/>
<?PHP
}else
{
?>
    <input type="Submit" value="Buy Now" />
<?PHP
}
```